# Finding the minimal value of an Expression

Tags: lagrange-multiplier

I was working on a problem:

"Given $x+2y+3z=15$, find the minimal value of $x^2+y^2+z^2$."

I tried to find the answer by balancing out each of the three variables. However, I there appeared to be a smaller value than the answer I found. Does anyone know how I am intended to solve this?

Comment: What value do you get when you use Lagrange multipliers?

Comment: What do you mean by “balancing out?”

Comment: Assuming you mean 'balancing out' is setting $x=2y=3z$: this only applies when you can use AM-GM, so $x,y,z$ must be all greater than $0$.

Comment: My guess is that the minimum is when $z=3k,y=2k,x=k$ and the maximum when $x=3k,y=2k, z=k$

Answer (score 1):

by cauchy Schwarz we get
$$(x+2y+3z)^2\le (x^2+y^2+z^2)(1+4+9)$$ so $$\frac{225}{14}\le x^2+y^2+z^2$$

Answer (score 1):

We are given that $f(x,y,z)= x^2+y^2+z^2$ with the constraint $x + 2y+3z=15$. Let's define $g(x,y,z)=x + 2y+3z - 15$ and then relate partial derivatives between $f$ and $g$. We will multiply all the partial derivatives of $g$ by our Lagrange multiplier $\lambda$.

$$2x=\lambda$$
$$2y=2\lambda$$
$$2z=3\lambda$$

We now need to solve all three of these equations for $\lambda$. Multiply all of them to get $2xyz$ on the LHS.

$$2xyz = \lambda yz$$
$$2xyz = 2\lambda xz$$
$$2xyz = 3\lambda xy$$

If we divide both sides by $\lambda$ then the LHS for all three equations will be $\dfrac{2xyz}{\lambda}$. Then, all three equations on the RHS are equal and we can write

$$yz=2xz=3xy$$

Therefore, if we review our constraint $x + 2y+3z=15$, we see that we form the following solutions:

$$x=0,~y=0,~z=5\tag{1}$$
$$x=0,~y=\frac{15}{2},~z=0\tag{2}$$
$$x = \frac{15}{14},~ y = \frac{15}{7},~ z = \frac{45}{14}\tag{3}$$
$$x = 15,~ y = 0,~ z=0\tag{4}$$

and if we evaluate these against $f(z,y,z)$

$$f(x,y,z)=25\tag{1*}$$
$$f(x,y,z)=\frac{225}{4}\tag{2*}$$
$$f(x,y,z)=\frac{225}{14}\tag{3*}$$
$$f(x,y,z)=225\tag{4*}$$

we see that $(3)$ returns the minimum value of $f(x,y,z)=\dfrac{225}{14}$.